# Can Mathematica Operators be combined in a linear fashion for readability?

Tags: functions, operators

Here's a simple example. Suppose we want to find the off-diagonal matrix of m:

```
m={{1,2},{3,4}}
```

This can be solved fairly simply by extracting a list of the diagonal elements, re-creating the diagonal matrix from these, and removing them from the full matrix to get the off-diagonal elements:

```
m - DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal[m]]
```

to get

```
{{0,2},{3,0}}
```

Now, this was a fairly simple solution to the given problem, but what I'm wondering is if there is a way to write something akin to

```
(Identity - DiagonalMatrix@Diagonal)[m]
```

To get the same result. In this simple example, not much would be gained by doing this, but I just thought it could be interesting in more complicated problems and help make the code resemble more closely the underlying mathematics in some cases.

Comment: `# - DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal[#]] &[m]` ? Of course you can add `Identity[#]` at the beginning.

Comment: This is pretty neat, I've only really used the pure function #& stuff for making special Sort and Order functions previously, but this is quite nice and shows I've not been using them enough. Not quite what I had in mind, but this question is more out of curiosity than absolute necessity.

Comment: Also look at `Composition` for chaining long functions. It will greatly improve the clarity of your code.

Comment: Also tried Map[Identity - DiagonalMatrix@Diagonal, m] unsuccessfully

Comment: In regards to Composition, thanks, that could prove useful for readability with complex functions
Identity[m] - Composition[DiagonalMatrix, Diagonal][m] does work

Comment: It seems that (at least in the case of some) functions can operate linearly over lists, which is sort of the converse problem to this one; e.g. Abs[{-1,3,-5}]={1,3,5} (As opposed to ~5.92 if it tried to interpret the action of Abs acting on the vector {-1,3,-5} to give, perhaps, the L2-norm; Norm[{-1,3-5},2] accomplishes this of course)

Comment: You should look at `Through` too, e.g. `Through[(f + g + h)[x]]` gives `f[x] + g[x] + h[x]`.

Comment: Through seems like the most promising thing so far, but I can't quite make it work for this problem. Any idea how to implement it with the given example?

Comment: @Steve It doesn't work for two reasons: `@` doesn't denote function composition, but function application (use `Composition` for function composition) and because `Through` only goes in one level while here we actually have an expression of the form `(a + (-1)*b)`, not of a simpler form `a-b`.  I'm afraid there's no easy and simple solution to your problem other than building pure functions as in `(Identity[#] - DiagonalMatrix@Diagonal[#]) &[m]`.

Comment: If it is just about readability in the front end, you can wrap some heads around every operator, define some `operatorApply`, and define neat layouts for both

Comment: Following Rojo's idea, you can do `operatorApply[f_[x__]] := 
 Replace[f, s_Symbol :> s[x], {0, Infinity}, Heads -> False]`.  See where this goes wrong: `operatorApply[(Sin + 1)[x]]` transforms to `Sin[x]+1`, all is fine.  Now what about `operatorApply[(Sin + Pi)[x]]`?  You get `Pi[x] + Sin[x]`, wrong!  This is probably why it's not a built-in function.  I don't see a good way around this problem, i.e. it's not a problem with my implementation but an inherent problem to the idea: it's not possible to distinguish functions from other symbols, e.g. constants.

Comment: @Szabolcs as to constants, there's the `Constant` attribute. But the idea included some operator wrapper symbol too, to make things more robust

Comment: @Rojo I wasn't referring to *your* idea.  I was trying to explain why I believe that such a function was not built into Mathematica.  There are just too many potential problems and too many situations where people can shoot themselves into the foot.  This one with `Pi` was just one example.  There are plenty more situations where something like `operatorApply` wouldn't fit well into the system.  There's a number of exceptions that would need to be implemented, such as `Function`, `Composition`, `InterpolatingFunction`, `ParametricFunction` and probably other things I haven't though of.

Comment: @Rojo Also, there are user defined SubValue functions, which I do use regularly. E.g. consider `fun[One][x_]:=x; fun[Two][x_]:=x^2`, where `One`/`Two` are symbols setting some option.  There's no way to tell that `One` is not a function and no way to tell that `fun[One]` *is* a function.  Generally, we come back to the point that it's impossible to reliably tell what is a function and what isn't.

Answer (score 0):

In version 10 we can use the new shorthand notation for `Composition` to write

```
Through@(Identity + Minus@*DiagonalMatrix@*Diagonal)[m]

(* {{0, 2}, {3, 0}} *)
```

As noted in the comments, `Through@(a - b)[x]` won't work the way we'd like because `a - b` is represented internally as `a + (-1)*b`. Composing with `Minus` gets around this problem.